# Continuous growth rate

Tags: limits, analysis

In an article I read the following text

"The discrete growth rate $p$ is the change of a time $t$ dependent quantity $A(t)$ between two points in time $t_{0}$ and $t$ relative to its initial value $A\left(t_{0}\right)$
$$
p=\frac{A(t)-A\left(t_{0}\right)}{A\left(t_{0}\right)}
$$
If we shorten the period more and more towards its initial point in time, i.e. if we form the limit value, then we obtain the continuous growth rate $w$ at this point in time. It is the instantaneous change of the quantity $A(t)$ at a concrete time $t_{0}$ relative to its value $A\left(t_{0}\right)$ at this time.
$$
w=\frac{1}{A\left(t_{0}\right)} \cdot \frac{d A}{d t}\left(t_{0}\right)
$$
"

Now I want to understand the step that leads from the discrete model to the continuous. Do you have a hint how the limit value has to be formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrete growth rate makes sense **only** if you define an interval. For example, if I say "the population doubles", you don't know if that happens in a year, a decade or a century. So before you go to the continuous case, you introduce the interval into the formula:
$$p\to\frac 1{A(t_0)}\frac{A(t)-A(t_0)}{t-t_0}$$
Noe $$\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac 1{A(t_0)}\frac{A(t)-A(t_0)}{t-t_0}=\frac 1{A(t_0)}\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{A(t)-A(t_0)}{t-t_0}=\frac 1{A(t_0)}\frac{dA}{dt}(t_0)$$

Comment: That is exactly what puzzled me. I also found other texts that defined $p$ the way I introduced above. They kind of incorporated $t - t_0$ through mentioning in the text above the formula that $p$ is the change between two points of time.